# Generating 1 second with avr and timer 0 for Atmega32A

Tags: avr, timer

dears:
we have to Generate 1 second with atmega32A and mikrobasic software.
so I have configured timer 0 and avr with this way:

```
const _THRESHOLD = 250 
TCCR0=0x04
TCNT0=0x06
OCR0=0x00
' // Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK=0x01
```

and overflow function:

```
sub procedure Timer0Overflow_ISR iv IVT_ADDR_TIMER0_OVF
' // Reinitialize Timer 0 value
TCNT0=0x06
if (counter1 >= _THRESHOLD) then
counter1 = 0
```

so with `TCCR0=0x04` WE USE 256 presqale with external clock 16MHz wich :

```
16MHz/256=62500
```

which means timer 0 clock is `1/62500=0.000016` Second
which `TCNT0=0x06` timer 0 over flow clock is `256-6=250` 
which take `0.000016*250=0.004` Second for one overflow of timer 0 with `TCNT0=0x06` .

so for creating 1 second, it needed to count timer0 overflow for `1/0.004=250` turn of timer0 overflow. the above codes are written based of this calcuation.
SO when we program this codes into atmega32A, for 5 minutes the clock is Lag for 5 seconds.

> Changes based of new comment.
>
> I have changed TCNT0=0x07 for 249 clock of timer0 and 1 clock for
>   overloading ti,er values. but still counter lag for 5 second  at 5
>   minutes .

please help me to correct my codes.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by creating 1 second?

Comment: @LongPham: They probably want to implement a clock, base on a 1 second counter that is off by about 5 seconds every 5 minutes.

Comment: it means generate

Comment: we want to generate 1 second with timer0 of Atmega32A

Comment: How do you increase the 0.004s tick? How is your uC's clock source?

Comment: Uhm, you cannot generate time. What you can generate using an ATMega is a **signal** that's high for 1 second and then low for 4 seconds.

Comment: The avr Crystal clock is 16MHz

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: OP is not stupid. There is obviously a language barrier preventing him from expressing it any better.

Comment: Do you have EXACTLY a 5 second difference EVERY 5 Minutes? Maybe your counter is just off by 1? It overflows at 255 and you reset it to 6.

Comment: @Rev1.0 If so, the error percentage is quite different.

Comment: Read the datasheet carefully. I have seen counters where it requires 1 cycle to re-load the counter thus a limit of 250 is actually 251 clocks.

Comment: @LongPham: True, it was just meant to point him into the right direction. And I don't think the 5min/5s is accurate. Its potentially several "1 counter off" things coming together.

Comment: I have changed TCNT0=0x07 to have 249 clocks + 1 click for reloading the counter. but now I have almost 5 second lagging for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "mikrobasic" compiled or interpreted? The website calls it a "compiler", but I have found that vendors play fast-and-loose with the distinction these days. Sometimes source code is compiled to an intermediate "bytecode" representation, which is then interpreted.

You have timer0 counting every 16 µs, which means that the ISR must update the `TCNT0` register within that amount of time in order for your calculations to be correct.

I find myself wondering whether the ISR actually does the write to `TCNT0` before it has already incremented several times, which would explain the roughly 1-part-in-60 error that you're seeing.

One experiment would be to see whether you get the correct timing by increasing the `TCNT0` value even more. Try setting `TCNT0 = 0x0B` in your ISR. If this gives you something closer to the correct timing, that means that there's a lag on the order of 64 µs between when the overflow interrupt occurs and when the write to `TCNT0` occurs. This would not be unheard of in interpreted code.

Comment: i have changed TCNT0 to 0x0B and time is almost correct. Thanks a lot

Comment: Does mikrobasic allow you to mix in assembly language at all? If so, your ISR would be a good place to take advantage of that, in order to reduce that lag.

Comment: mixing is able but i dont know assembly codes.

Comment: Well then, there's a learning opportunity for you!